# Ecto - Return records with timestamps grouped by date in a single query

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Currently I have a list of appointments in a table with the following columns:

```
id | start_time (timestamp with tz) | duration (minutes)
```

In order to group these appointments by a 7 day period, I am fetching appointments for each day and manually grouping them like this:

```
one_hour = 60 * 60
today = DateTime.utc_now()
week = Enum.reduce(0..6, %{}, fn day, acc ->
  date = DateTime.add(today, one_hour * day * 24, :second) 
  just_date = DateTime.to_date(date)
  appointments = (from a in Appointment, where: fragment("?::date", a.start_time) == ^just_date) |> Repo.all
  Map.put(acc, just_date, appointments)
end)
```

I am wondering if I can fetch all these records in a one shot rather than 7 different database calls and get the same result as below.

```
{
    "2021-08-03": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "start_time": "2021-08-03T05:11:30Z",
            "duration": 30
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "start_time": "2021-08-03T06:11:30Z",
            "duration": 30
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "start_time": "2021-08-03T07:11:30Z",
            "duration": 30
        }
    ],
    "2021-08-04": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "start_time": "2021-08-04T05:11:30Z",
            "duration": 30
        }
    ],
    "2021-08-05": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "start_time": "2021-08-05T05:11:30Z",
            "duration": 30
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "start_time": "2021-08-05T10:11:30Z",
            "duration": 30
        }
    ],
    "2021-08-06": [],
    "2021-08-07": [],
    "2021-08-08": [],
    "2021-08-09": []
}
```

So far I have tried something like below query but I am unsure if this is possible to do with just one query to the database since PostgreSQL does not allow for outputting records like this(?)

```
  def appointments_count_grouped_by_date(query) do
    query
    |> group_by([a], fragment("date(?)", a.start_time))
    |> select([a], %{date: fragment("date(?)", a.start_time), count: count(a.id)})
    |> order_by([a], asc: fragment("date(?)", a.start_time))
  end

  result = Appointment |> appointments_count_grouped_by_date
           |> Repo.all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with getting all the appointments within the date range

```elixir
start_date = Date.utc_today()
end_date = Date.add(start_date, 7)
appointments =
  from a in Appointment,
  where: fragment(
    "?::date BETWEEN ?::date AND ?::date",
    a.start_time, ^start_date, ^end_date)

records = Repo.all(appointments)
```

and then reshaping the outcome in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) code. If you want to receive already grouped result, inhecting `group_by/2` clause should not be complicated.

Comment: I am not sure why I didn't think of this earlier, this solved my issue after doing a manual grouping of the `records` into day buckets. Thanks!